# Options to secure internal electronics

Tags: arduino, pcb, pcb-design, design, breadboard

I am designing a small and compact measurement device housing an arduino and breadboard.

I have a number of small electronic PCB's and components I would like to house securely inside and I was wondering if people can recommend ways to secure them so they don't rattle about inside.

The case is made from plastic and 3D printed.

I want the components to be removable in the case of fault or replacing, so I was considering velcro as an option.

Any better ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use screw ? Nylon screw are more or less soft and won't damage much your plastic housing.

Comment: Standoffs come in metal threaded and plastic for MOBO's which can also be glued in place with Polyurethane construction subfloor adhesive.

Comment: I've thought about nylon screws, however I want the device to be compact so the base is filled with the arduino and breadboard and remaining space on the side walls hence why I was thinking to velcro strap it inside. I suppose nylon screws could work, but I just don't really want bits sticking out/inside the finished product.

Comment: The first thing to come apart will be the breadboard.

Comment: Design the 3D printed case with location grooves to hold the boards.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 3D printed box I suggest that you re-design the 3D data set to include printed in standoffs on the inside of the box that match the board mounting holes. These standoffs can be designed with a center hole in them so that you can mount your boards with short self taping screws.

Such standoffs would look similar to this one from a standard molded plastic enclosure.

[image]

After all, 3D printing is all about customization - make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Anything really. Most of the time it amounts to including a hole in the board.

Technically double sided sticky tape and velcro are not ESD safe and should not be used in a real design, but if your a hobbyist it probably wouldn't matter.

Some things that I've used:

Zip ties - Just measure the zip tie and put a hole of appropriate size in the board

Standoffs and mechanical fasteners
[image]

PCB [card guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=pcb%20edge%20connectors&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju-fGy8OrRAhUX3YMKHUPBBQAQ_AUIuQEoAQ#tbm=isch&q=pcb%20card%20guide%20):
[image]